# Which Windows is best for two concurrent users?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, audio, vmware-player

I'm running Windows 7 in VMPlayer under Linux. I made some changes to Windows 7 to allow it to have two people logged in at the same time. However when I do this the sound lags behind on the host machine.

Is there a different version of Windows where I am less likely to have this problem?

Comment: Try disabling the sound device in VMPlayer?

Comment: How are you logging in Windows 7 with two users at the same time? RDP?

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem isolated to just audio or is it a general slowing of the whole system, a system of which being the sound lag?

As per the comment above; I'd try disabling the sound device on the VM.

Failing that, try limiting the resources given to the VM, if it's a taxing of the whole system that could be the issue.

If you're still struggling you could try a server version of Windows; they're optimised for multiple users via terminal services so should be able to cope better with having many users logged in at once.

Answer (score 0):

A server version of Windows (2003, 2008, 2008 R2) would be better for this.